# ¿Como ejecutar este método para refrescar la tabla en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, plugin

Estoy usando este plugin para mis tablas responsive:
http://doit.maryland.gov/webcom/responsivetables/responsive-tables.html

Si tengo las filas insertadas directamente en el html todo funciona perfecto.
pero estoy agregando filas a la tabla por medio de javascript de la siguiente manera.

mi tabla

```
<table id="tablalineasdepedido" data-role="table" class="ui-responsive table-stripe col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Articulo</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                                <th scope="col">$Unitario</th>
                                                <th scope="col">%Descuento</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Almacén</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="encabezadotablalineaspedido">


                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>



$("#encabezadotablalineaspedido").append(htlmaddlineaarticulo);
```

Cuando las filas son agregadas estas no toman los estilos responsive que asigna el script al iniciar. Revisando el script, este tiene un método de refresh pero no sabría como llamarlo desde mi script después del `append`. El código del script es algo así, el script completo está en el link y no puedo usar jquery mobile porque me descuadra todos los estilos.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    var pluginName = "responsiveTables",
        defaults = {
            classes: {
                table: "ui-table",
                reflowTable: "ui-table-reflow",
                cellLabels: "ui-table-cell-label"
            },
            initSelector: '[data-role="table"]',
            mode: "reflow"
        };
function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.refresh(true);
        },

        refresh: function (create) {

            var self = this,
                trs = this.element.find( "thead tr" ),
                options = this.options;
```

ya he probado agregando jquery mobile y funciona correctamente usando   **$("#tablalineasdepedido").table("refresh");** 
pero necesito usar solamente este plugin ya que si agrego todo jquery mobile me deforma todos los estilos.

Comment: ¿El Id de la tabla es el mismo que el de este código?, sugiero agregar el código completo a su pregunta para que así podamos entender mejor porqué sucede esta situación.

Comment: La tabla tiene los atributos `ID` y `class` con valores diferentes al establecido en el javascript; creo que es por esto que el plugin no le funciona. Compruebe en el navegador, con las herramientas de desarrollador "F12", la consola del navegador al ejecutar este código y agregue la información que la consola pueda mostrar.

Comment: Si Mauricio es el mismo. ya he probado agregando jquery mobile y funciona correctamente usando `$("#tablalineasdepedido").table("refresh");` pero necesito usar solamente  este plugin ya que si agrego todo jquery mobile me deforma todos los estilos.

Comment: Revisa la [documentación del plugin](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/) y actualice su pregunta con lo que ha escrito en su comentario anterior. Buena suerte.

Comment: Precisamente de esa documentación saque $("#tablalineasdepedido").table("refresh"); pero tenia que agregar jquery mobile y la intensión es no hacerlo, el plugin que estoy usando es una versión modificada y esta estructurado de una manera diferente.

Comment: el código que añadiste esta completo o sólo añadiste parte de él, por que veo aue no haz cerrado varias opciones.

Comment: Si correcto solo es parte del código porque es bastante extenso.

Comment: intenta agregar primero jQuery mobile y luego la libreria principal

Comment: Revisa la documentación algún método de destruir la instancia y recrearla Ejemplo : table.destroy(); de JQuery Datatable